# Express.js, how to pass jwt cookie to Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, jwt

I have a login route that eventually create a jwt cookie named `access_token`. After the login the client will receive this cookie and will send it on every request. However I didn’t found a way to pass this cookie on to Socket.io.

Server side login route :

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
      const {email, password} = req.body
      const user = await UserModel.findOne({email})
      const isMatch = await user.checkPassword(password)
      if (isMatch) {
        const userToken = JwtService.createToken(user.id)
        return res.cookie("access_token", userToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
        }).status(200).json({user:user.toJSON(),message: 'login success'})

    }
 }
```

Socket :

```
this.io = new socketio.Server(expressServer, {cors: {origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}})
    this.io.use((socket,next)=>{
        console.log(socket.handshake.headers.cookie); // undefiend
        next()
    })
```

Client :

```
  this.socket = socketIOClient(process.env.SOCKET_BASE_URL, {auth: {userId}});
```

Server :

```
         import express, {RequestHandler} from 'express';
        import http from 'http'
        import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
        import cors from 'cors';
        import {router} from '@router';
        import dotenv from 'dotenv'
        import mongoose from 'mongoose';
        import {SocketService} from "@services";
        
        const expressApp = express();
        
        const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
        dotenv.config()
        
        expressApp.use(cors({
            origin: true,
            credentials: true
        }));
        expressApp.use(express.json() as RequestHandler);
        expressApp.use(cookieParser());
        expressApp.use('/', router)
        
        const httpServer = http.createServer(expressApp);
        new SocketService(httpServer)
        
        httpServer.listen(port, async () => {
            console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
            try {
               await mongoose.connect('mongodb://guess-it-mongo-dev:27017/guess-it', {connectTimeoutMS: 1000});
               console.log('connected to mongo server')
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You want your socket and your app as one server, right ?

Comment: the express service and socket service on the same project / server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Solution

Assuming that you have only one cookie which is your `jwt`, you could get it with the `socket` param like so :

```
const token = socket.handshake.headers.cookie.split("=")[1];
```

If you have many cookies, you need to use some cookie parser and give it the `socket.handshake.headers.cookie` to parse it,  for example:

```
function getCookie(cName) {
   const name = cName + "=";
   const cDecoded = decodeURIComponent(socket.handshake.headers.cookie);
   const cArr = cDecoded.split(';');
   let res;
   cArr.forEach(val => {
      if (val.indexOf(name) === 0) res = val.substring(name.length);
      })
   return res;
}
const token = getCookie("jwt"); // if your token is called jwt.
```

### 2. Troubleshot

If the given solution is not working for you, make sure you are setting up your app and socket this way to have them as a single server (feel free to change the port):

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

server.listen(9000, () => {
   console.log("server runnig on port " + 9000);
});
```

And the client should be connecting like this (with the same port as the server) :

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

io("http://localhost:9000/", {
      transports: ["websocket"],
    });
```

### 3. An use case

For example, in the code
below, I am authenticating every connection with a [middleware](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/):

```js
io.use((socket, next) => {
const token = socket.handshake.headers.cookie.split("=")[1];
if (token) {
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, (err, decodedToken) => {
    if (err) {
      next(new Error("invalid"));
    } else {
      User.findById(decodedToken.id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          next(new Error("invalid"));
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  next(new Error("invalid"));
}
});

//if authentication is ok, the code below will get executed 
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // do things
})
```

Comment: socket.handshake.headers.cookie is undefined for me 

and i am clearly can see the Set-Cookie on the response headers from login route 

and i am creating the connection to the socket only after login

Comment: Can edit your question and add the relevant code please ?

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look please (below).

Comment: still undefined :/

my server is configured exactly like that

Comment: I edited my answer again for the client part. Look below at the end.

Comment: wow ... can't believe it  transports: ["websocket"] actually fixed it 
can you explain ?

Comment: Really glad it worked out. To understand the transports part, you could read [here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-initialization/#low-level-engine-options).